# Trying to convert a requests.get object to a json and getting an error

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I'm new to python and programming in general so bear with me..

So i've pulled a request from an API but when I try to convert to json, i'm getting the following error

```
File "Transport Finder.py", line 44, in <module>
    routejson = route.json()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 897, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is the code i'm currently using, this was working previously but I just came back to it and now getting this error.

```
route = requests.get(f'http://router.project-osrm.org/route/v1/driving/{StartLL};{EndLL}?alternatives=false&annotations=nodes')
routejson = route.json()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error output, you are getting an empty response.
Maybe there is some issue with the url or you need to pass some headers along with the request.

You can `print(route.text)` to debug the output of your request and then parse it later once you get a satisfactory output.

Comment: that's it, I had a gap in the damn variables, d'oh.